# Configuration Error with ProtoBuf WCF Behaviour

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am trying to set up protobuf as my serializer for wcf. I have added the following elements to my web.config of my service

```
    <behavior name="ProtoBufSerializationBehavior">
      <protoBuf/>
    </behavior>

<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="protoBuf" type="ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoBehaviorExtension, protobuf-net"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

However, I get the following error when trying to browse my endpoint

*Cannot add the behavior extension 'protoBuf' to the service behavior named 'ProtoBufSerializationBehavior' because the underlying behavior type does not implement the IServiceBehavior interface.*

My service endpoint currently isn't even using this behaviour configuration at this point

I'm sure it's something stupid I'm doing wrong, but can't seem to find it.

Comment: Got it working, my behaviour needed to be in the endpointBehaviour collection not the serviceBehavior

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working, my behaviour needed to be in the endpointBehaviour collection not the serviceBehavior